# Flattening Multiple Arrays

Tags: arrays, r

I am trying to model cultural dissemination. In the program, I have five characteristics and nine potential outcomes per characteristic.

```
dimension <- 10 
characteristics <- 5 

world <- array(0, dim=c(dimension, dimension, characteristics))

for (i in 1:dimension){
  for (j in 1:dimension){
    for (k in 1:characteristics){
      world[i,j,k] <- sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 1)
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to flatten the array and create a unique identifier for each potential variation. For example, a world where each array[1,1]=(0,0,0,0,0)=1 all the way to: (9,9,9,9,9)=10^5. Also, this: (1,0,0,0,0)!=(0,0,1,0,0) etc. Any suggestions on how to flatten the dimensions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hashing the arrays like `digest::digest(world[1, 1, ])` will get you a unique value for each possible sequence. I'm not sure what you aim to use the IDs for though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example with the desired shape?  How 'flat' do you want it?  This stacks the five characteristics on top of each other, resulting in a 10*5 rows and 10+1 columns (the extra column denotes the 'characteristic').

```
library(magrittr)
lst_ds <- purrr::map(seq_len(characteristics), ~tibble::as_tibble(world[,,.]))
ds <- lst_ds %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "characteristic")
```

produces:

```
# A tibble: 50 x 11
   characteristic    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
            <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1              1     3     3     1     6     3     6     9     7     0     0
 2              1     7     4     8     8     8     9     7     2     4     4
 3              1     0     6     7     2     7     5     1     1     7     4
 4              1     0     6     3     4     5     1     9     3     1     3
 5              1     1     5     2     1     1     9     6     8     3     2
 6              1     6     5     6     5     4     3     2     0     6     1
 7              1     2     7     1     4     4     4     8     1     1     0
 8              1     0     7     6     1     3     9     0     8     6     1
 9              1     1     2     4     8     1     9     2     8     1     5
10              1     2     9     1     6     8     0     3     1     6     2
11              2     6     2     7     7     0     1     1     2     9     0
12              2     0     0     7     5     7     4     9     1     4     6
# ... with 38 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your "(9,9,9,9,9)=10^5" notation differently now.  Do you want every possible combination enumerated (ie, the 10^5) part, accompanied by a count of how many times each quintet appears?

Transform the cube into a list of 2d data frames.  And some dimension indices if you need them somewhere.

```
library(magrittr)
lst_ds <- purrr::map(seq_len(characteristics), ~tibble::as_tibble(world[,,.]))
lst_ds <- purrr::map(lst_ds, function(d) { dplyr::mutate(d, dim1= seq_len(nrow(d))) })
```

Transform to an entity-attribute-value style of dataset (ie, super tall).

```
ds_eav <- lst_ds %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "characteristic") %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key=dim2, value=value, -characteristic, -dim1) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    characteristic  = paste0("c", characteristic),
    dim2            = as.integer(sub("^V(\\d+)$", "\\1", dim2))
  )
```

Widen so each *observed* quintet occupies its own row.

```
ds_quintet <- ds_eav %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key=characteristic, value=value)
```

Enumerate the possible quintets.

```
ds_possible <- tidyr::crossing(
  c1 = 0:9,
  c2 = 0:9,
  c3 = 0:9,
  c4 = 0:9,
  c5 = 0:9
)
```

Count the observed quintets, then right join them with all 10^5 possible values.  And replace the `NA`s (that never occurred in `ds_obs` with zeros).

```
ds_obs <- ds_quintet %>% 
  dplyr::select(-dim1, -dim2) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(
    frequency = n()
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::right_join(ds_possible, by=c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5")) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    frequency   = dplyr::coalesce(frequency, 0L)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
```

Which looks like:

```
 A tibble: 100,000 x 6
      c1    c2    c3    c4    c5 frequency
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <int>
 1     0     0     0     0     0         0
 2     0     0     0     0     1         0
 3     0     0     0     0     2         2
 4     0     0     0     0     3         0
 5     0     0     0     0     4         0
 6     0     0     0     0     5         0
 7     0     0     0     0     6         1
 8     0     0     0     0     7         0
 9     0     0     0     0     8         0
10     0     0     0     0     9         0
# ... with 99,990 more rows
```